# Unexpected increase of resistor's resistance after overload

Tags: resistors, resistance, fuses

I was trying to make a so-called *bridgewire* (an electric fuse to initiate fireworks remotely). I took a low-power 1206 SMD resistor (1.8 Ohm, 0.25W) and applied high current to it (a pack of three powerful 18650 Li-Ion batteries yielding around 11V). I had expected the resistor to undergo a catastrophic failure and melt due to Ohmic heating. However, nothing has happened at all!
I connected the circuit to a current meter and saw that the flow was only 0.05A. Measured the resistor and it was 80Ohm! Thinking it might have been a faulty one, I took a new resistor, measured it (it was showing 2 Ohm, as expected), connected to the circuit but the results were exactly the same: no melting and sudden significant increase of resistance.

**Question one**: why has this happened?
**Question two**: what was I doing wrong?

Comment: *and melt due to Ohmic heating* Explain why that is more likely to happen than the material providing the resistance simply **burning off** which results in an increased resistance. Also: **if** the resistance would become lower, what would happen? Even more current would flow, more power would be dissipated in the resistor, it would get even hotter. Would it "melt more" in that case?

Comment: Why not buy some bridgewires?

Comment: Good point @Bimpelrekkie. However, when I was researching the topic, I've found a few articles by amateur rocket builders who use low-power, low resistance SMD resistors and say "they would burn off fiercely, igniting fuel/fuse". That's what I had been expecting!

Comment: You can't count on one manufacturer's product behaving the same as another's when you are operating it so far off-label.

Comment: Because they're roughly 100x more expensive than SMD resistors @Andyaka and because I wanted to play with a project (obviously) :)

Comment: *...they would burn off fiercely* in my view that is more similar to my "...the material providing the resistance simply burning off" than your "*melt due to Ohmic heating*". If something **melts** it can only ignite some fuel if the temperature gets above the fuel's self-ignition temperature. I think you're **misinterpreting** what the rocket people write. If the resistor **burns** then for sure the fuel will be ignited (assuming the right conditions for that exist).

Comment: I've had a lot of success with 1/8th watt leaded resistors, but driven from an inductor in series, so that as they open harmlessly, they then arc across, which does the lighting.

Comment: Yes @Bimpelrekkie, the problem was - literally nothing happened (not melting, not burning, it wasn't even hot to touch after a minute). The resistor looked completely normal, with no charring or anything... looks like its internal wiring got silently burned which increased the resistance and stopped further temperature increase!

Comment: There are better component choices for this... Try a tant bead capacitor wired up backwards, usually a fairly reliable source of fire.

Comment: LOL why the downvotes? :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, or unfortunately, resistor manufacturers have generally made their components more fire-safe as time has gone on, so that when grossly overloaded, they tend to fail like [T. S. Elliot's Hollow Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hollow_Men), not with a bang but a whimper.

You can force them to fail with fire if you put an inductor in series with the battery. That way, even if they open safely, the inductor will then drive an arc, which will usually light stuff.

Comment: "Between the motion and the act..." "...Falls the shadow." "So... the mysterious Doctor knows his Eliot!" (couldn't resist :) +1 for the Hollow Men reference, +1 for your help and advice Neil :) Cheers mate!